# SQL update query with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I tried below queries on 400 records in STG_S_CUST table MySQL

I have below query which takes little long time(0.1500s)

```
UPDATE STG_S_CUST AS stg
       INNER JOIN S_CUST AS s
               ON stg.SRC_NM = s.SRC_NM
                  AND stg.SRC_KEY = s.SRC_KEY
SET    UPDATE_IND = 0,
       stg.S_ID = s.S_ID,
       stg.M_ID = s.M_ID
WHERE  stg.PROCESSED_IND = 1
```

On using `EXPLAIN` in query I am getting

[image]

And when I rewrite the query it takes(0.0318s)

```
UPDATE STG_S_CUST AS stg
       INNER JOIN (SELECT stg.stg_id AS stage_id,
                          s.s_id   AS s_id,
                          s.m_id   AS m_id
                   FROM   STG_S_CUST AS stg
                          INNER JOIN S_CUST AS s
                                  ON stg.src_nm = s.src_nm
                                     AND stg.src_key = s.src_key
                   WHERE  stg.processed_ind = 1) innerQ
               ON stg.stg_id = innerQ.stage_id
SET    stg.update_ind = 0,
       stg.s_id = innerQ.s_id,
       stg.m_id = innerQ.m_id
```

On using `EXPLAIN` in query I am getting

[image]

I am not able to understand this scenario. I had thought second query will take longer duration as it include 2 inner join.

Can anyone please share the view on this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN <statement> to know which indezes are used.

Comment: @Jens, I have updated the question with results of EXPLAIN query. But I am not aware of this details, can you please shower some lights on this?